# Cifrado de SQL Server 2005 a 2019 AWS

Tags: sql-server, aws

Hola a todos buenos días,

Realice una migración de una base de datos de On Premise:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64)   Dec 10 2010 10:38:40   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

A AWS:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16-GDR) (KB5014353) - 15.0.4236.7 (X64)   May 29 2022 15:55:47   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Todo el tema me funciona pero tengo un problema, hay una base de datos que utiliza el cifrado simétrico a nivel de columna, estas son las llaves simétricas en el servidor antiguo:

[image: Llaves simetricas en servidor antiguo]

Y esta es la configuración en el servidor nuevo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema va cuando intento descifrar, por el cifrado de la MasterKey en AES256 no me permite hacerlo.

Mis preguntas son:
¿hay alguna manera de cambiar el cifrado para que sea con el TRIPLE_DES en el nuevo servidor?

¿Hay alguna manera de cambiar el cifrado para que sea con el AES256 en el antiguo servidor?
Con esto generaría backup nuevamente y restauraría, entendiendo que ya no habría problema

La única opción es descifrar en el servidor antiguo, generar backup y volver a cifrar en el servidor nuevo?

Mil gracias a todos por leer.

Comment: NIST publicó en 2018 que 3DES debía deprecarse por inseguro y desde 2023 ya debe aparecer deshabilitado en todas las aplicaciones. Es decir, no debería habilitarse en mssql 2019. No sé si el cifrado pueda _cambiarse_ en el viejo servidor pero lo más fácil suena que es descifrar, extraer y guardar con el nuevo cifrado. Posiblemente el cambio de cifrado implique exactamente eso así que, para qué gastarle vida a MSSQL 2005

Comment: Lo entiendo, y tienes toda la razón, la opción mas fácil es esa, y, a primera impresión es lo más indicado, pero precisamente por ello la pregunta es esa, ¿hay algo alterno que se pueda hacer? ¿Existe la posibilidad?

gracias por comentar bro.